# How to check existence of object in sublist in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How to verify the existence of sub-child object inside the parent object using kotlin

I am trying to find if the parent object (Module.kt) has an object of it's sub child list

**Parent class : Module.kt**

```
data class Module
(
        var id: String? = ObjectId().toHexString(),
        var name: String = "",
        var description: String = " ",
        var frames : MutableList<Frame> = mutableListOf<Frame>(),
        var functions : MutableList<Function> = mutableListOf<Function>(),
        var created_at: Date = Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
        var updated_at: Date = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
)
```

**Child class : Frame.kt**

```
data class Frame (

        var id: String? = ObjectId().toHexString(),
        var name:String  = "",
        var level:String = "",
        var moduleID:String = "",
        var subFrames : MutableList<Frame> = mutableListOf()

    )
```

Example : Cheking the existence of a submenu in the root menu

[example image explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CAvs.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Use MutableMap instead

```
data class Module
    (
    var id: String? = ObjectId().toHexString(),
    var name: String = "",
    var description: String = " ",
    var frames :MutableMap<String,Frame> =  mutableMapOf(),
    var functions : MutableList<Function> = mutableListOf<Function>(),
    var created_at: Date = Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
    var updated_at: Date = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
)

data class Frame (
    var id: String? = ObjectId().toHexString(),
    var name:String  = "",
    var level:String = "",
    var moduleID:String = "",
    var subFrames : MutableMap<String,Frame>? = mutableMapOf()

)

var module = Module() 
module.frames["LAB"]?.subFrames?.get("CODE")?.subFrames?.get("HTML")?.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that will search in the root list only `modules.frames` , I would like to search on all sub lists !!